# ui.router will not allow to show changes in my HTML

Tags: angularjs

Below is my config for using ui.router. I make a change to left.html thinking I would see my changes, yet I don't.  I have to change the name of the html file to see changes. How do reflect changes in my HTML?

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div ui-view="left"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div ui-view="right"></div>
</div>


ms.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("manageservices");
  $stateProvider
    .state('manageservices', {
      abstract : true,
      templateUrl: 'static/app/manage-services/manageservices.html',
      controller: 'ManageServicesCtrl',
      cache: false,
      reload: true
    })
    .state('manageservices.main', {
      url: "/manageservices",
      views: {
        'left': {
          templateUrl: 'static/app/manage-services/left.html',
          controller: 'ManageServicesCtrl',
          cache: false,
          reload: true
        },
        'right': {
          templateUrl: 'static/app/manage-services/right.html',
          controller: 'ManageServicesCtrl',
          cache: false,
          reload: true
        }
      } //end views 

    })
})
```

Comment: Are you sure the views are even loaded? Can you see your browser making a http call to that template?

Comment: No but if I change the name of the template it loads and I can see my changes.  I a now on left26.html.